# asp.net sqlcommand not doing as it should - debugging help req

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, debugging, sqlconnection

This is a really odd situation that I can't seem to work out where the problem lies.

I have a simple ASP textbox and button, on clicking the button I have a simple sqlconnection/command routine perform a simple update to a database based on the text value of the textbox.

Code:

```
Using myConnection As SqlConnection = New sqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sqldbconn").ConnectionString)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim strSQL As String = "insert into users(name) select @name"
    Dim myCommand As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection)
    myCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(create_Parameter("@name", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, Data.ParameterDirection.Input, txName.Text))
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection.Close()
End Using
```

create_Parameter is just a simple tested function which performs the 2-3 lines it normally takes to create a parameter object.

The problem I have, is that the value added to the database is always a comma, followed by the text given in the textbox.

I have performed response.write's prior to the ExecuteNonQuery call to check both the Parameter value and the CommandText, which are fine and as expected.  If I copy what's expected into a management studio query window, it works fine.. users is a simple table with varchar column, no triggers or constraints etc.  There are no other sub's in the ASP code other than what I've shown.

So now I'm stuck, what else can I do to work out where/why this comma is being added to my insert statement???

Cheers!

Comment: Please post your `create_Parameter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably nothing to do with your issue, but I wold normally write an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (name)
VALUES  @name
```

Comment: I was all ready to say that I had that originally, but changed it just to see what would happen... changed it back and the problem's gone away!  Have no idea why it would affect anything but thank you :)